# Unidentified error in ORA-06512 in triggers

Tags: oracle, triggers

what is wrong? everything seems fine. but....

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER salary_change
BEFORE UPDATE
OF emp_salary
ON employee
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (((NEW.emp_salary-OLD.emp_salary)/OLD.emp_salary)>0.2)
DECLARE
    limit NUMBER(7);
BEGIN
    limit:=:OLD.emp_salary*1.2;
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR (-20000,'rule violated. cannot increase beyond : '|| limit);
END;
```

I have errors:

> ERROR at line 3:
>        ORA-20000: rule violated. cannot increase beyond : 3360
>        ORA-06512: at "SYSTEM.SALARY_CHANGE", line 5
>        ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'SYSTEM.SALARY_CHANGE'

Answer (score 0):

The ORA-06512 just tells you what line in your code caused the error. In this case it's line #5 in the trigger, which apparently corresponds to the RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR call.

So, apparently `((NEW.emp_salary - OLD.emp_salary) / OLD.emp_salary` is greater than 0.2. Given that the limit value from the message is 3360, this would mean that OLD.EMP_SALARY was 2800, and NEW.EMP_SALARY was greater than 3360.

Best of luck

Answer (score 0):

[USING RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR ALSO GIVES ERROR ORA-06512 AND POSSIBLY ORA-04088](https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/Oracle%20Database%20Products/1005760_6.html)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER hr.salary_change
    before UPDATE
    OF salary
    ON hr.employees
    FOR EACH ROW
    WHEN (((NEW.salary-OLD.salary)/OLD.salary)>0.2)
    DECLARE
        limit NUMBER(8,2);
        salary_high  exception;
        pragma exception_init(salary_high ,-20001);
BEGIN
        limit:=:OLD.salary*1.2;

        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR (-20001,' rule violated. cannot increase beyond :'||to_char(limit));

        exception
        when   salary_high  then
        :NEW.salary:=:OLD.salary;
        dbms_output.put_line(dbms_utility.format_error_stack);
END;

SQL> SET SERVEROUT ON
SQL> select salary  from hr.employees where employee_id=198;

    SALARY
----------
      3900

SQL> update  hr.employees set salary=5900 where employee_id=198;
ORA-20001:  rule violated. cannot increase beyond :4680
1 row updated.

SQL> select salary  from hr.employees where employee_id=198;

    SALARY
----------
      3900

SQL>
```